# Get also non-matching strings from preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have some text with `<img>` tags in is that I need to divvy up. It's in the format

```
<img.../> Text text text <img.../>text text text<img.../> text text text
```

I have my regex qworking in `preg_match_all` so that I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img ... />
            [1] => <img ... />
            [2] => <img ... />
            [3] => <img ... />
        )
```

But it would be really nice if I could get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img ... />
            [1] => text text text 
            [2] => <img ... />
            [3] => text text text 
            [4] => <img ... />
            [5] => text text text 
        )
```

I've tried a few things but I really don't have a good understanding of PCREs. I don't want to use `preg_split` if I can avoid it because each of the images tags are different.

(I understand that a general HTML parser cannot be written with regular expressions, but in this case, I think this will work because the input data that I'm working is in the form I described. There aren't going to be any nested image tags that I'll need to worry about.)

**PS** I've tried `/!<img.+>/`, `/!(<img.+>)/`, and `/(!(<img.+>))/` to get the non-matches, but it returns an empty array. I don't know a good way to debug regexes to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Your reason for avoiding `preg_split` is unreasoned. Please elaborate. If you already can match the tags and their variations, then ... Yes, why?

Comment: It's just a bother to loop through the matches and run `preg_split` on the full text to wind it down to nothing. If I can do the work in the `preg_match_all` command, why bother writing the loop?

Comment: What loop now? `preg_split` (with the right parameter) already breaks up the source into specifically the chunks you want.

Comment: @mario `preg_split` takes one string as an argument. I have multiple *different* strings that I need to split it by. I would have to run `preg_split` for each match I got from `preg_match_all`, whittling down the text each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your issue (*or actual code* for that matter) is, but:

```
$r = preg_split('#<img[^>]+>#', $source, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <img.../>
    [1] =>  Text text text 
    [2] => <img.../>
    [3] => text text text
    [4] => <img.../>
    [5] =>  text text text
)
```

In place of a proper regex, you can keep using your fixed strings (I presume) with `#<img1>|<img2>|<img3>#` of course.

Comment: Ugh! Long day at work, was thinking "hard-coded string" and not "regular expression" :P Public embarrassment ensues...

Answer (score 0):

You can have the information you want just not quite in the right format by doing this:

```
preg_match_all('~(<img[^>]*>)([^<]+)~', $str, $matches);

//if inside your "text text text" areas you have other html tags, use this:
preg_match_all('~(<img[^>]*>)(.+?)(?=<img|$)~', $str, $matches);
```

At this point, `$matches[0]` contains the entire matched string. `$matches[1]` contains all of the matches from the first set of parenthesis and `$matches[2]` contains all of the matches from the second set of parenthesis.

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => <img.../> Text text text 
    [1] => <img.../>text text text 
    [2] => <img.../> text text text 
  )
  [1] => Array ( 
    [0] => <img.../> 
    [1] => <img.../> 
    [2] => <img.../> 
  ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
    [0] =>  Text text text 
    [1] => text text text 
    [2] =>  text text text 
  ) 
)
```

Now if you really need it formatted the way you would like, just add these lines of code:

```
$answer = array();
foreach($matches[0] as $i=>$match){
  $answer[] = $matches[1][$i];
  $answer[] = $matches[2][$i];
};
```

`$answer` now looks like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => <img ... />
  [1] =>  Text text text 
  [2] => <img ... />
  [3] => text text text 
  [4] => <img ... />
  [5] =>  text text text 
)
```